# Random value in struct field

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to learn some C and I've started with a simple deck of cards program.

The card is struct containing two ints for face and suit. And I'm building a deck by allocating 52 cards, and going thorough a loop.

```
card *Deck = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card) * 52);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 14; j++){
        Deck->face = j;
        Deck->suit = i;
        Deck += sizeof(card);
    }
}
Deck -= sizeof(card) * 52;
printDeck(Deck);

free(Deck);
```

I have a `printCard` function that takes a single pointer and prints the values, and a print deck function that calls `printCard` 52 times. If i print the cards as they are being created, everything goes well, but if i print the cards after all have been created for some reason I get a segfault at the 6th card. I fired up `gdb` and noticed this output:

```
Seven of Diamonds<br>
(null) of Diamonds<br>
Nine of Diamonds<br>
```

The rest of the output is normal.
When checking for the value of the 6th card i got:

```
(gdb) p c->face
$10 = 2675
```

If i am skipping the 6th card the output is fine and everything works the way it should.
I'm new to C but i can't really see how that value got put in that field in my code.

```
struct card{
    int face;
    int suit;
};

void printCard(card* c){
    printf("%s of %s\n", face_str[c->face], suit_str[c->suit]);
}
```

Edit:

The printDeck code:

Before:

```
void printDeck(card* c){
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        printCard(c);
        c += sizeof(card);
    }
}
```

After:

```
void printDeck(card* c){
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        printCard(c);
        c++;
    }
}
```

printCard didn't changed:

```
void printCard(card* c){
    printf("%s of %s\n", face_str[c->face], suit_str[c->suit]);
}
```

Comment: [Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Can you add one [mcve]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your code is this line:

```
Deck += sizeof(card);
```

Here, `Deck` is a `card *` (pointer to `card`). If you want to advance of one position, pointer arithmetic does the job for you, and doing `Deck + 1` already advances `sizeof(card)` ahead. Adding or subtracting from a pointer `p` always advances `sizeof(*p)`.

The correct code would be:

```
Deck += 1;
// or 
Deck++;
```

The same mistake is done after the loop, here:

```
Deck -= sizeof(card) * 52;
```

Which should be:

```
Deck -= 52;
```

> I'm new to C but i can't really see how that value got put in that field in my code.

When you wrongly modify the variable `Deck`, you end up accessing memory that is beyond the size of the allocated chunk (which is `sizeof(card) * 52`). This is undefined behavior in C, and therefore trying to print such a value could result in random values being printed (if not worse).

---

I would suggest you to completely avoid modifying the value of `Deck`, and instead index it like an array:

```
card *Deck = malloc(sizeof(card) * 52);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 14; j++){
        Deck[i*13 + j]->face = j;
        Deck[i*13 + j]->suit = i;
    }
}

printDeck(Deck);
free(Deck);
```

Comment: It could as well be `for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) { Deck[i]->suit = i%4; Deck[i]->face = i/4+1; }`

Comment: @chmike of course... there are countless ways of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

It would be interesting to show us the code of the `printDeck` function.

The problem you have in the given code is `Deck += sizeof(card)`. You assumed that this would move Deck `sizeof(card)` bytes further. But that is not correct. When Deck is a pointer on `card`, incrementing Deck by one will increment its address by `sizeof(card)` bytes.

So your code should be

```
card *Deck = malloc(sizeof(card) * 52);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 14; j++){
        Deck->face = j;
        Deck->suit = i;
        Deck++;
    }
}
Deck -= 52;
printDeck(Deck);

free(Deck);
```

You might have made the same error in `printDeck`.

Comment: "_incrementing Deck by one will increment its address by sizeof(char) bytes._" => incrementing Deck by one will increment its address by sizeof(**card**) bytes. This isn't helped by the very topsy-turvy use of Capitals for instances and small letters for types... :S

Comment: @underscore_d oops, sorry. You are right. I’ll fix that.

Comment: That fixed it! Changing from Deck += sizeof(card) to Deck++ resolved the problem. But i still don't understand why i was getting the random value in the 6th card. It was always that card the rest of the cards were printed properly

Comment: @vlad27 Undefined behaviour is undefined. Accessing memory out of bounds invokes undefined behaviour. It's not interesting or useful to worry about why some particular manifestation of UB occurs.

Comment: @vlad27 there might be a problem in the code of `printDeck` too. Until we can see its code, we can’t provide an explanation of what you saw.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right. I simply copy pasted the code and fixed the bug. I'll fix that mistake.